# html label value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to set the value of a label tag by invoking a function? I mean, something like the following:

```
<label>Convert_Code(4)</label>
```

where `Convert_Code` is  javascript function that converts the received code (4 in the example) to a string.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to fire the function when the label is clicked, or do you just want to change the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using the following syntax:

```
<label> {{Convert_Code(MyArray_One_Entry.Code_ID)}}</label>
```

where the ng-repeat runs through all the elements of an array named `MyArray`.

Comment: How would anyone know that you were talking about angular in the first place?